# Filling out a basic form perl WWW::Mechanize

Tags: perl, twitter, www-mechanize

Im trying to fill out the 'form' on the twitter search home page (link in the code defined as $url) its very basic a box for what you want to search and a search button. But its giving me a lot of difficulty, I cant seem to get it to work. 
Here is the portion of my script where i'm filling out the 'form'

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();

my $url = "https://twitter.com/search-home";
```

blah. blah. blah.

```
$mech->get($url);
$mech->submit_form(
    form_number=> 1,
    fields => {
    query => $tweetsearch,
    button => "Search",
    }
);

print $mech->uri();
```

When it prints it, it prints out $url meaning it didnt do anything where it should print https://twitter.com/searchsrc=typd&q=from%3Anikestore%20%22jordan%22%20%22concord%22%20%22now%20available%22%20since%3A2014-5-2
Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using wrong form:

```
$mech->submit_form(
    form_id => "search-home-form",
    fields  => {

        q => "#YourTimeHasCome #MVP #NBA2K15",
    },
);
```

Comment: Thanks, thats what I did, for a few hours I thought it was that I was 'misspelling' the button name.

Answer (score 0):

Like many modern websites, Twitter tends to make heavy use of JavaScript.

From the WWW::Mechanize [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW%3a%3aMechanize):

> Please note that Mech does NOT support JavaScript, you need additional software for that. Please check "JavaScript" in WWW::Mechanize::FAQ for more.

The [FAQ entry](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aFAQ#JavaScript) mentions these other modules which may have better JS support:

- [Gtk2::WebKit::Mechanize](https://metacpan.org/pod/Gtk2%3a%3aWebKit%3a%3aMechanize)
- [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aFirefox)
- [WWW::Scripter](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW%3a%3aScripter)
- [WWW::Selenium](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW%3a%3aSelenium)

Many websites also offer computer-friendly APIs. [Here is Twitter's API documentation.](https://dev.twitter.com/docs)